# Differences between \subject command and \startsection in ConTeXt

Tags: context

I am wondering which are the conceptual differences between `\subject` and `\startsection ... \stopsection` commands. From my document's compilation I can see a that the former produces an "unnumbered" section. So, the purpose of `\subject` is to replace `\section*{}` in `LaTeX`? If that it's the answer, then can I include `\subject`'s contnent into TOC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are perfectly right that `\subject` is just an unnumbered `\section` in ConTeXt.  The reason is that there doesn't exist a thing as starred commands in ConTeXt.  One could have has `\unnumberedsection` instead but then who wants to type that?

All the default sectioning commands are listed on the [Titles page in the Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Titles).

On the [Table of Contents page in the Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Table_of_Contents#Including_unnumbered_heads_in_the_ToC) there are instructions on how to get unnumbered sections to appear in the table of contents.  It is very easy and a minimal working example is shown below.  The `list` parameter in `\setupcombinedlist` can be extended with all kinds of other sections like, e.g., `subsubsubsection`.

```
\setuphead [subject] [incrementnumber=list]
\setupcombinedlist
  [content]
  [list={chapter,section,subject,subsection}]

\starttext

\completecontent

\startsection[title={Test section}]
  Lorem ipsum
\stopsection

\startsubject[title={Test subject}]
  Dolor sit amet
\stopsubject

\stoptext
```

[image]